# 'Equations have different numbers of arguments' when deciding whether a tree is complete or not

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I'm tring to use a function to decided whether a binary tree is complete or not, but the compiler keeps telling me "equations have different numbers of arguments".

Guess the error is about syntax, but I just can't find the right format.

```hs
data BinaryTree a = Leaf a | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)

...

decideComplete :: BinaryTree Int -> Bool
decideComplete (Node l _ r) = (decideComplete l) && (decideComplete r)
decideComplete Leaf v = True
```

Comment: You should use brackets, so `(Leaf v)` instead of `Leaf v`.

Comment: If `l` and `r` are complete trees of different height, `Node l _ r` is not complete, but your code claims otherwise. You could try to use an auxiliary function for computing the height. Alternatively, make your function return either "tree is complete and of height H" or "tree is not complete". You could use `Either Int ()` or `Maybe Int` as a return type, or -better- define your custom type `data Result = Complete Int | NotComplete`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `decideComplete` function takes a `BinaryTree Int` (perhaps you want to generalize this to `BinaryTree a`). `Leaf` is not a `BinaryTree a`, it is a data constructor that takes a parameteter, you thus should add brackets, like:

```
decideComplete :: BinaryTree a -> Bool
decideComplete (Node l _ r) = (decideComplete l) && (decideComplete r)
decideComplete (Leaf v) = True
```

That being said, your function will here generate `True` for *all* trees (unless of course the tree has an infinite number of nodes, but in that case it will simply get stuck in an infinite loop, or run out of memory). Indeed: for all `Leaf`s it will return `True`, and for a `Node l _ r`, it will return `True` given `decideComplete` on both `l` and `r`, but there is no way this can return `False`, since eventually the subtrees will be `Leaf`s, so that node will be `True`, and so by induction, all your `BinaryTree`s will be `True`.

In order to check if a binary tree is complete, all the levels except the last one should be full. The last level should contain nodes at the most far left as possible.

Comment: "That being said, your function will here generate True for all trees." Not for infinite trees (you obviously know that, but still might be worth mentioning for anybody else who reads the answer).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! I've fixed it now XD